# Hidden sheet results in corrupted output of the export-sheet-as-PDF URL of Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a script to generate some PDFs, save them to drive and email them if this was required.

The script works fine, except for one issue: When I hide the sheet called "TrafficAgentPDF" and run my script, it creates the PDF in Drive, but it's corrupted somehow. Cannot be opened by google; when opening it in a browser, it's blank. Unhide the sheet, and it all works.

The TrafficAgentPDF sheet does a vlookup on another sheet, to show images instead of values. The images are small icons, and only 3 are used. A red traffic light, amber traffic light and green. (Thought I'd mention that in case it was a weird rendering issue.)

Here is my script. If anything is unclear, let me know and I will annotate it.

```
function getAgentName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getRangeByName('Header').clearContent();
  ss.getRangeByName('Scores').clearContent();
  ss.getRangeByName('Comments').clearContent();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PDF Creator");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2")
  var value = range.getValue();

  if(value != 0)
    getAgentData(value);
  else
    Browser.msgBox("You need to go to the sheet named PDF Creator and put an agent name in cell A2");
}

function getAgentData(value){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1")
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), sourceSheet.getLastColumn());
  var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
  sourceValues.sort(function(a, b) { return b[0] - a[0] });

  var agentData = [];
  var commentsData = [];
  for(i = 0; i < sourceValues.length; i++) {
    // Defines the data layout for PDF.
    var agentName = sourceValues[i][2];
    var dateTime = sourceValues[i][3];
    var callType = sourceValues[i][7];
    var opening = sourceValues[i][8];
    var rootCause = sourceValues[i][9];
    var rootFix = sourceValues[i][10];
    var process = sourceValues[i][11];
    var consumer = sourceValues[i][12];
    var control = sourceValues[i][13];
    var wrapup = sourceValues[i][14];
    var dpa = sourceValues[i][15];
    var score = sourceValues[i][22];
    var comments = sourceValues[i][16];

    var agentRow = [dateTime, callType, opening, rootCause, rootFix, process, consumer, control, wrapup, dpa, score];
    var commentsRow = [dateTime, comments];

    if(agentName == value && agentData.length < 9) {
      agentData.push(agentRow)
      commentsData.push(commentsRow)
    }
  }
  agentData.sort(   function(a, b) { return b[0] - a[0]; });
  commentsData.sort(function(a, b) { return b[0] - a[0]; });

  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("AgentPDF");
  destSheet.getRange("A1").setValue(value + "'s Quality Score card");
  destSheet.getRange(6, 1, agentData.length, agentData[0].length).setValues(agentData);

  destSheet.getRange(18, 1, commentsData.length, commentsData[0].length).setValues(commentsData);

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  emailSpreadsheetAsPDF();
}

function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PDF Creator");
  var now = new Date().toString();
  var weekCommencing = sheet.getRange("C1").getValue();
  var coachEmail = sheet.getRange("C4").getValue();
  var coachName = sheet.getRange("A4").getValue();
  var agentName = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var agentEmail = sheet.getRange("C2").getValue();
  var sendEmail = sheet.getRange("A6").getValue();

  var subject = "Quality Scorecard for - " + agentName + " created on: " + now;

  var monthNames = [
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
    "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
    "Aug", "Sep", "Oct",
    "Nov", "Dec"
  ];

  var day = weekCommencing.getDate();
  var monthIndex = weekCommencing.getMonth();
  var year = weekCommencing.getFullYear();

  var clean = day + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year;

  var bodyCoach = "Hello " + coachName + ". Please find attached "+ agentName + "'s quality scorecard." + " Week commencing " + clean;
  var bodyAgent = "Hello " + agentName + ". Please find attached your  quality scorecard." + " Week commencing " + clean;

  /** Specify PDF export parameters
   * // From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
   * exportFormat = pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
   * gridlines = true / false
   * printtitle = true (1) / false (0)
   * size = legal / letter/ A4
   * fzr (repeat frozen rows) = true / false
   * portrait = true (1) / false (0)
   * fitw (fit to page width) = true (1) / false (0)
   * add gid if to export a particular sheet - 0, 1, 2,..
   */
  var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   // export as pdf
        + '&size=a4'                           // paper size
        + '&portrait=1'                        // orientation, false for landscape
        + '&fitw=true&source=labnol'           // fit to width, false for actual size
        + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
        + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
        + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
        + '&gid=1809314965';                   // the sheet's ID
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext , {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      }
  });

  var file = response.getBlob().setName(agentName +"'s Quality Score Card Week Commencing: " + clean + '.pdf');
  writeFiles(file, clean);

  if (coachEmail != "no email"){
    GmailApp.sendEmail(coachEmail, subject, bodyCoach, {attachments:[file]});
  }

  if(sendEmail == "Yes"){
    GmailApp.sendEmail(agentEmail, subject, bodyAgent, {attachments:[file]});
  }

  ss.getRangeByName('Header').clearContent();
  ss.getRangeByName('Scores').clearContent();
  ss.getRangeByName('Comments').clearContent();
  ss.getRangeByName('AgentName').clearContent();
  ss.getRangeByName('Coach').clearContent();
  ss.getRangeByName('SendEmail').clearContent();
}

function writeFiles(file,clean) {
  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID HERE");
  var subFolders = rootFolder.getFolders();  

  var testResult = false;
  while(subFolders.hasNext() == true){
    var folders = subFolders.next();
    if(folders == clean) {
      testResult = true;
    }
  }

  if(testResult == false){
    rootFolder.createFolder(clean);
  }   
  var destFolder = rootFolder.getFoldersByName(clean).next();

  if (destFolder.getFilesByName(file.getName()).hasNext() == false){
    destFolder.createFile(file);
  } else {
    var warning = Browser.msgBox("Warning", "This PDF already exists. If you wish to overwrite this file, press OK to continue.", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    if (warning == "ok"){
      destFolder.getFilesByName(file.getName()).next().setTrashed(true);
      destFolder.createFile(file);
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT BELOW**

After some poking and prodding and testing, it seems when either using a URL to create a PDF, or the `getAs` function, hidden sheets are always omitted.

A simple test:

```
function whatever() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pdf = ss.getAs('application/pdf'); 
  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID HERE");
  rootFolder.createFile(pdf);
}
```

If you have any hidden sheets in that spreadsheet, they will be missed out. Is this by design or a bug?

I'm using the URL method in which I can explicitly define the GID of the sheet I want, and I own the spreadsheet, so should it work?

After discussions with another SO user, I've asked that very question to Google.

[Bug report submitted to Google](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5671)

Comment: I created a dummy sheet and I can replicate the problem. The sheet is here. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19b4GLbcIszxHRwabWIw2ms3QOjpWPKAJ-jQcI4MANS4/edit?usp=sharing Feel free to make a copy. You may have to change email and folder vars

Comment: it's definitely the 'var response = ' bit it's struggling with. With the sheet hidden, or unhidden. It generates a URL. When manually visiting this URL, it'll download a PDF. If the sheet the PDF get's its data from is hidden. PDF is always blank. When you unhide it, PDF is normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 'unhiding' the sheet, 'using' the sheet, and then 'hiding' the sheet when done. There is a .hideSheet() method, but there is no .unhideSheet() listed on their API documentation.

to 'unhide' the sheet use the .activate() method.

================

According to the API documentation:

activate()

"Activates this sheet. Does not alter the sheet itself, only the parent's notion of the active sheet."

```
// This example assumes there is a sheet named "first"
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var first = ss.getSheetByName("first");
 first.activate();
```

Here is the API documentation link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#activate

It would be nice if they explained why you would need to alter "the parent's notion of an active sheet" in the docs but they don't.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Will give it a go and report back

Comment: This works. But it unhides the sheet. 
So what is the difference between using that and .hideSheet and .unhideSheet

Comment: .unhideSheet() isn't listed on their API documentation as far as I can see. It may be a depreciated method, in which case for the sake of longevity of the script you should use .activate() instead. But yes, the idea is to 'unhide' the sheet, 'use' the sheet and then 'hide' the sheet

Comment: It could also be a bug on their side, unless they specifically intend for hidden sheets not to be available to GAS scripts in terms of retrieving content. It seems unlikely they would intend that...

Comment: I'm sure I've read data from hidden sheets before. But never a sheet with images.  Will have to create a few examples and try to see if I can narrow down the scope of when it works and doesn't work

Comment: That would be helpful to know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100866/discussion-between-munkey-and-zach-smith).

Comment: I can read data from a hidden sheet. But it seems the creation of the PDF here always breaks, even if it's pure text, if the sheet is hidden. Perhaps the URL part of the script hasn't go the authority to view the hidden sheet

Answer (score 0):

I found out that scripts I wrote do not work on hidden sheets, so after some research found this works to unhide a sheet:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Google URL");

  var print1  = ss.getSheetByName("Print1"); // Sheetname is 'Print1'

// unhide sheet
   print1.showSheet().activate();
   ss.setActiveSheet(print1, true);
```

Hope this helps!