# Google Apps Script returned code 500

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I really hope you can help me.

This google apps script has been working fine for converting a google sheet into a PDF and emailing it, while also saving a copy of the PDF to a specific Google Drive folder; but now it's not stopped working and giving me the below error. Nothing's changed on my end and last successful attempt/send was April 2016.  Were there G-apps updates in the past year?

Here's the error:

```
Request failed for https://docs.google.com/a/filmclosings.com/spreadsheets/d/1Shy55DRkwKdSGayWQYKV6bCPMvm2qfgK3zD_plyi8lE/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&size=letter&portrait=false&fitw=true&source=labnol&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false&fzr=false&gid=1082764768 returned code 500. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" ><head><meta name="description" content="Web word processing, presentations and spreadsheets"><meta name="viewport" ... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

and here's my google apps script:

```
/* Send Spreadsheet in an email as PDF, automatically */
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {

// Send the PDF of the spreadsheet to this email address
//var email = "amit@labnol.org"; 
  var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var Output = originalSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Output-BASIC");
var email = Output.getRange("M2").getValue();

// Subject of email message
// The date time string can be formatted in your timezone using Utilities.formatDate method
//var subject = "PDF Reports - " + (new Date()).toString();
var subject = "Film Closings Finance Plan";

// Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
// Or use SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("<<SPREADSHEET URL>>");
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Shy55DRkwKdSGayWQYKV6bCPMvm2qfgK3zD_plyi8lE');
//var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Email Body can  be HTML too with your logo image - see ctrlq.org/html-mail
//var body = "PDF generated using code at ctrlq.org from sheet " + ss.getName(); 
var body = "Hello and thank you for your order - attached is the PDF of your Finance Plan from FilmClosings.com";

var url = ss.getUrl();
//var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Shy55DRkwKdSGayWQYKV6bCPMvm2qfgK3zD_plyi8lE/edit";
url = url.replace(/edit$/,'');


/* Specify PDF export parameters
// From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
  exportFormat = pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  gridlines = true / false
  printtitle = true (1) / false (0)
  size = legal / letter/ A4
  fzr (repeat frozen rows) = true / false
  portrait = true (1) / false (0)
  fitw (fit to page width) = true (1) / false (0)
  add gid if to export a particular sheet - 0, 1, 2,..
*/

var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   // export as pdf
              + '&size=letter'                       // paper size
              + '&portrait=false'                    // orientation, false for landscape
              + '&fitw=true&source=labnol'           // fit to width, false for actual size
              + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
              + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
              + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
              + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id

var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();

//make an empty array to hold your fetched blobs  
var blobs = [];

for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {

  // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheets[i].getSheetId(), {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });

  //convert the response to a blob and store in our array
  blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName(sheets[i].getName() + '.pdf');

}

//create new blob that is a zip file containing our blob array
var zipBlob = Utilities.zip(blobs).setName(ss.getName() + '.zip'); 

//optional: save the file to the root folder of Google Drive -- Jeff activated this and changed to go a specific Drive folder
DriveApp.getFolderById('0B59I-GV_lvsJaHdOUEZVMktzMHc').createFile(blobs[0]).setName(email+ ' Finplan');

// Define the scope
Logger.log("Storage Space used: " + DriveApp.getStorageUsed());

// If allowed to send emails, send the email with the PDF attachment
if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {cc:"jeff@filmclosings.com", attachments:blobs[0] });
   //GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {attachments:[zipBlob]});

}
```

I really appreciate your time and insight.

Best,

JD

Comment: You are using OAuth.  It's probably a problem with your `token`.  I think there was some kind of change, but I'm not sure.  Are you using a library for the OAuth authorization?

Comment: The only news that I know about for OAuth is at the following post [Link to Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/+EricKoleda/posts/K7P7pHefXir)  If the problem is not an authorization issue, it might be something with the search string parameters.  Have you experimented with removing each search string parameter one by one from the end and trying each one?

Comment: thanks @SandyGood for your response.  when i first attempted to use the script today, it did ask me to authorize the email (like it did the very first tike i used it).  i just assumed since its been 11 months that the authorization had lapsed.  there were no errors during the authorization.  just when running the script.

Comment: @sandy when I ran the script inside the editor, this is the line that got highlighted for the error:  **var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheets[i].getSheetId(), {**

Comment: Use `Logger.log(url + url_ext + sheets[i].getSheetId())` to get the URL that is being used.  Run the code, and then VIEW the LOGS.  Copy the URL out of the Log print out.  Put the URL into the browser, and hit "Enter" or refresh the browser tab.  Check to see if the file downloaded.

Comment: Thanks @Sandy, yes the PDF downloaded.

Comment: Oh, okay.  It downloaded.  Great.  So, the URL must be correct and working.  That makes me think it's an authorization issue.  Unfortunately, I really don't know much about the OAuth process.  You might post your question on the [Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)  And I would edit your question, and exclude code not related to the download or OAuth, and maybe add the OAuth tag.

Comment: Fixed it!  I noticed the gid # in the error was different from the gid # in the active sheet referenced in the script.  Turns out there was a hidden sheet that the script was defaulting to for some reason. when I deleted the hidden sheet, the problem was fixed.  script works!  Thanks again @Sandy !

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Discovered that hidden sheets need to be 'unhidden' for a script to work on it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50439365/4742611

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden sheet that is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there were no hidden sheets in the spreadsheet. What I did was to identify at which sheet the error starts showing up, duplicated this sheet and deleted the previous one, and then ran the function again. It worked seamlessly!